# Fancybox - keep prev/next arrows in same place

Tags: jquery, navigation, fancybox, arrows

I'm using Fancybox for an image gallery.

Images are different widths so the arrows move around (in or out) according to the image width.

My client would like the arrows to stay in one place so you can easily click through a set without having to move back and forth to click. I've looked through all of the Fancybox questions here and haven't found an answer. I've tried changing the CSS and can't get this to work.

The gallery is [here](http://southamptonbuilding.com/relaunch/southampton-building-gallery.shtml).

Comment: if using fancybix v2.x, why don't you use the buttons helper? check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ and see the source code

Answer (score 2):

You could, for example, change CSS position of navigations links to fixed - http://jsfiddle.net/yJFxS/

```
.fancybox-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.fancybox-nav span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-next span {
    right: 40px;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
    left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you disable the standard prev/next buttons with a plugin option "showNavArrows". Then you can make your own prev/next buttons and place them fixed or absolute in the fancybox-overlay (for example upper right corner). If you have a look at the fancybox api, you'll see that you can trigger pref/next with:

```
$.fancybox.next
$.fancybox.prev
```

http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: Just for the record : http://fancybox.net/api refers to an older version of fancybox, which is not compatible with the version the OP is using.

Comment: I'm sure all versions have a prev/next api :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think this is beyond my capabilities - I don't know javascript. I would use the button helper except the client doesn't like the look of that. I thought there might be a simple way to do this or something I could copy/paste. But thank you for your ideas.